# In how many ways can 2 motors and 2 switches be selected?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm not sure if order matters in this question. I believe that order matters the way that it is worded with **selected**, but any insight would help with the question below:

The supply department has 8 different electric motors and 5 different starting switches. In how many ways can 2 motors and 2 switches be selected for an experiment concerning a tracking antenna?

**My answer:** If order matters and repetition isn't allowed, I believe that it would be:

```
P(13,4) or 13 Pick 4
```

**Note**: This question is a suggested problem, not anything I need to hand in or school related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\dbinom{8}{2}$ ways to choose the $2$ motors from the $8$ available.

For **each** such choice, there are $\dbinom{5}{2}$ ways to choose the switches, for a total of 
$$\binom{8}{2}\binom{5}{2}.$$

**Note:** $\dbinom{n}{k}$ is the standard mathematical notation for the number called $n$ Pick $k$ in the OP.

The numerical answer to the problem is $280$.

Comment: Almost had it! Thank you

Comment: Isn't the answer this? -> (8!/6!)(5!/3!), which is 1120

Comment: The usual interpretation of select (say for the motors) is that the *order* of selection doesn't count, all that matters is which pair of motors you ended up putting in the truck to take away.

Comment: That makes more sense.